# SocketIO: disconnect client by socket id?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a Node server with SocketIO and several connections. How is it possible to disconnect an existing socket based on its ID? There are rooms, an admin in each room and other connections. My goal is to enable the admin socket to make any other socket disconnect based on its ID.

A workaround would be to send a message to the client-to-be-kicked to ping the server back: `io.to(socketId).emit('commit-suicide!');`, then it sends back an `"I-am-so-suicid"` message and the server calls `socket.disconnect()`. Now this is clearly not the optimal solution...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On server side you can access `io.sockets.connected` which holds all connected sockets:

`io.sockets.connected[socketId].disconnect();`

Comment: Maybe because the answer is almost 4 years old. Not sure if it is still valid for the current version of SocketIO.

Comment: Yeah i think so

Answer (score 0):

You can hash it in a JSON object

See [Socket#id:String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976501/socketio-disconnect-client-by-socket-id)

`var json = {};
... //create your serversocket, accept a connection
json[Socket.id] = Socket`